# Create new window in Arc browser extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, arc-browser

Ultimate goal is to open new tabs in different **windows** in Arc browser (**not** in new tab or in 'Little Arc')

I'm currently trying to write an extension (based on "New Tab, New Window" https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/new-tab-new-window/dndlcbaomdoggooaficldplkcmkfpgff) to work similar with "Open Link in New Window" right-click command. I'm on macOS.

**Question:** In chrome extension, how to open new window? The code below works in Chrome, but in Arc it opens a new Little Arc, not a new window.

```
import {getOption, setOption} from "./lib/option.js";

chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener(function(tab){
    if (tab.index == 0){
        console.log('First Tab'); 
        return;
    } 
    const createData = {
        tabId: tab.id, 
        focused: true, 
        incognito: tab.incognito, 
        setSelfAsOpener: true, 
        type: "popup"
    }; 
    chrome.windows.create(createData); 
});
```

Note: In Arc, all windows list the same tabs, all tabs belonging to the current space. So it's enough if the extension opens a new window and activates the respective new tab in it.

Comment: Remove `type: "popup"`

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't work. Without "popup", the Little Arc doesn't even open the tab, it remains blank and tab is lost.